# Menu from the Contre Jour app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to do a menu like the one that "Contre Jour" game has, with 3 elements spinning in a circle when user drags left and right. I'm using CALayers with CATransforms to position them in a 3d spinning wheel (no problem so far).

I need a way (maybe with NSTimers?) to calculate in-between values, because CoreAnimation just interpolates values, but if you NSLog them, it's just gonna show the start and the end, or just the end. I need all the in-between values, I need to snap the wheel movement when I release the finger (touches ends)in one position (there are 3 elements, each one shoud be at 120 degrees.

Comment: How is this question connected to the IDE in use (Xcode)?

Answer (score 0):

My guess and am quite sure I'm correct is that they are using a game engine such as Unity3D or Cocos2D or any other of the many to manage their sprites, animations, textures, physics and basically everything. Trying to replicate it outside of game engine will most likely result in crummy performance and a lot of hair pulling. I would suggest looking into a dedicated game engine and give it a shot there.

Comment: Yeah that was my thought as well, it's just that i don't wanna use external libraries for a small issue in my app! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly what Contre Jour does with the spinners, anyway, I think that a reasonable approach for your case is using a `UIPanGestureRecognizers` to update the status of your spinning wheels according to the panning.

Now, it is not clear what you do to animate the spinning wheel (if you could provide some code, this would help understanding exactly what you are trying to do), but the idea would be this: instead of specifying an animation ending point far away from the starting point (and letting Core Animation do all the handling for you, even when the dragging has stopped), you would only modify the status of the spinning wheel in small increments.

If your only issue is stopping the animation when the dragging stops, you could try calling  `removeAnimationForKey` on your layer to halt a specific animation.

Comment: When you say " modify the status by small increments",  what do u make reference to?  How can I modity a status in small steps??     Thank you

Comment: what I referred to is: you have an animation in place now; this is changing the value of some property from an initial value to a final one across a time span; here, you are modifying the status (state?); doing this in small increments would mean that the final value is "close" to the final one and the time step is "small" (whatever close and small might mean in your case to give a smooth animation). does this clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Look into CADisplayLink. This works very much like an NSTimer, except its refresh rate is tied to that of the display, so your animations will be smoother than if you were to use timers. This will allow you  to calculate all the in-between values and update your control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you are asking, but I do have one insight for you: To get the in-between values of an in-flight animation, query the layer's presentationLayer property. the property that's being animated will have a value that's a close approximation of it's on-screen appearance at the moment you fetch the value.